# Setter is not working in Swift

Tags: ios, uiview, swift

I'm trying to extend `UIView` with shortcuts to setting size and origin, as done in `Obj-C` [here](https://github.com/michalkos/UIView-Positioning).
Getters work great, but setters don't. Any ideas why? What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code rewritten from Obj-C to Swift:

```
extension UIView {

...


var height : CGFloat {
get {
    return self.frame.size.height
}
set {
    var r = self.frame;
    r.size.height = height;
    self.frame = r;
}
}
```

And here is another one, since `CGRect` properties are "val"

```
var width : CGFloat {
set {
    self.frame.size.width = width
}
get {
    return self.frame.size.width
}
}
```

But none of this setters works

This works great, but it's too long :)

```
self.frame.size.width = 100
```

Thank you for you help!

Comment: in the setter you need to use the `newValue` instead of `height` in the second line. the concept is same in your other setter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The setter name and enclosing parentheses is optional. If you provide
>   a setter name, it is used as the name of the parameter to the setter.
>   **If you do not provide a setter name**, the default parameter name to the
>   setter is **newValue**.

Change your `set` method to:

```
set {
    self.frame.size.width = newValue
}
```